# Solution of piecewise second order linear difference equatio.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, finite-differences

I am trying to solve $$-\dfrac{1}{h_{i+1}}Y_{i+1}-\left(\dfrac{1}{h_{i+1}}-\dfrac{1}{h_{i}}-\left(h_{i+1}+1\right)\dfrac{a}{2\epsilon}\right)Y_{i}+\left(1-(h_{i+1}+1)\dfrac{a}{2\epsilon}\right)Y_{i-1}=0,$$
where $Y_0$ and $Y_N$ are given.

The solution can be found by substituting $Y_i=Aw^i$ which results in an quadratic equation from which $w$ is found. My problem I need a solution for values $1\leq i\leq N/2-1$, $i=N/2$  and $N/2+1\leq i\leq N-1$. If the problem was to find the solution for $1\leq i\leq N-1$, then I would not have problems.

The value of $h$ for $1\leq i\leq N/2-1$ is $h_1$ and for $1\leq i\leq N-1$, it's $h_2$